# Jquery custom function with CallBack

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I have the following function:

```
Test.prototype.showToken = function () {
         $('#modal').modal('show');

         $('#modal').find('#btnOk').click(function (e) {
             // here I want to callback
             var returnValue = '123';
         });

     $('#modal').find('#btnProcess').click(function (e) {
             // here I want to callback cancel
             var returnValue = '456';
         });
     },
```

Now I have this in other function:

```
$.Test.showToken();
```

This works fine... Now I want inside my `showToken` to have a `CallBack` so when the click button happens I get in my other function the callback triggered. For example:

```
$.Test.showToken(function(e){

   // here would like to get the trigger when the btnOK is clicked and also be able to get the returnValue.

   // here would like to get the trigger when the btnProcess is clicked and also be able to get the returnValue.

});
```

> Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accept callback functions in your function arguments.

```
Test.prototype.showToken = function (options) {
   $('#modal').modal('show');

   $('#modal').find('#btnOk').click(options.okButtonCallback);

   $('#modal').find('#btnProcess').click(options.processButtonCallback);
}
```

Then when you call your function, you can pass callbacks to do special things.

```
$.Test.showToken({okButtonCallback: function(){
   // This will run on the ok button press.
}, processButtonCallback: function(){
   // This will run on the process button press.
}});
```

Comment: Is it possible to do:  $.Test.showToken(okButtonCallback: function(){ }, processButtonCallback: function(){ }); ?

Comment: Change the usage example to follow your recent changes!

Comment: So $.Test.showToken() will keep the same format? I can't add the okButtonCallback: function()... etc?

Comment: It's there. I just goofed it.

Comment: Very nice!!, Let me try it

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
Test.prototype.showToken = function (okCallback, processCallback) {
         $('#modal').modal('show');

         $('#modal').find('#btnOk').click(function (e) {
             // here I want to callback
             var returnValue= ???
             okCallback(returnValue)
         });

     $('#modal').find('#btnProcess').click(function (e) {
             // here I want to callback cancel
             processCallback()
         });
     },
/// ...

/// Usage:

Test.showToken(function(retValFromOk){ 
   // from OK
   console.log("From ok", retValFromOk);
}, function() {
   // from process
});
```

Comment: Thanks, how can I get the returnValue?

Comment: I hate seeing (rage? jealousy? "no pick mine"?) downvotes on working solutions.  +1.